# Is Glassfish 4.1 supported in AIX 6.1.0.0?

Tags: java, glassfish, aix, glassfish-4

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.2.2 on a AIX machine and it is working fine. The company's security policy requires me to upgrade it to the latest version, but everytime I try to deploy my application (the same that is working fine in version 3.1.2.2) I get the error `Type javax.rcm.ResourceAttributes not present` and a nasty stack trace afterwards.
I read the server's specification and it is not clear if it will run on AIX or not. Previous releases had a separate distribution specific for AIX, but that is not the case now. 
Does anyone know if it just not compatible or if it is some sort of bug in the JDK implementation?

Kind regards,

Carlos Ferreira

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish 4.x and higher is not "supported" on anything. The reason is that Oracle have withdrawn commercial support, so GlassFish is only available as an open source edition.

If you do need commercial support, [the Payara project exists to provide commercial support](http://www.payara.co.uk/home) and custom builds of GlassFish.

Coincidentally, there is [a recently opened issue on their Github relating to known issues with GlassFish on the IBM JDK](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/248), so it is probably worth commenting on that issue (or creating a new one) with your errors and stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Payara Blue is the version of Payara that should run on IBM AIX on the IBM JDK. [Get Payara Blue from the Payara WebSite](http://www.payara.fish/downloads) Payara is derived from GlassFish 4.x Open Source Edition.